# How to evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$$

From graphs, I know that the limit is exactly $-1$ (this function limit is "$b$" from $f(x)=ax+b$, where $f(x)$ is asymptote of another function).

I managed to get to a point, by using l'Hospital rule, where my limit equals 0. I've checked calculations few times, and can't find, where the mistake is.

Could you please show me steps, how to evaluate this limit?

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor series? If so, you can (i) use the fact that $\arctan x + \arctan \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x>0$; (ii) use this to study instead the limit of $\left(\frac{1}{u}+u\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan u\right)-\frac{\pi}{2u}$ when $u\to 0^+$; (iii) use a (low-order) Taylor expansion of $\arctan u$ when $u\to 0$ to deal with that.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not, but I think, that this limit should be possible to calculate with just l'Hospital rule.

Comment: Most likely. But You can also just use the above, forget about Taylor series, and simply use in (iii) that $\frac{\arctan u}{u} \xrightarrow[u\to 0^+]{} 1$. (E.g., seeing it as the derivative of $\arctan$ at $0$). This will give you the limit, without invoking any "big" theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}=0$$
and
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$$

you have 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$$
$$=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(x\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$$
$$=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(x \left(\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}}{1/x}$$
which has the indeterminate form  $0/0.$ Now use l'Hospital
$$=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{1/(1+x^2)}{-1/x^2}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{-x^2}{1+x^2}=-1$$

Answer (score 5):

Set $x=\dfrac1u$. We have, for  $x\to+\infty$ ($u\to 0^+$):
\begin{align*}\Bigl(x+\frac1x\Bigr)\arctan x-\frac{\pi x}2&=\Bigl(u+\frac1u\Bigr)\arctan\frac1u-\frac\pi{2u}=\Bigl(u+\frac1u\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac\pi2-\arctan u\Bigr)-\frac\pi{2u}\\
&=\frac{\pi u}2-u\arctan u -\frac{\arctan u}u\to 0-0 -(\arctan u)'_{u=0}=-1.
\end{align*}